# Add CAP_SYS_PTRACE for a user in LTS 16

Tags: permissions, pam

I would like to be able to attach to a process with gdb.  The process has my uid, but the executable file is set-gid.  So, apparently, I'm learning about PAM.  It's my understanding any process attaching to a set-gid process needs `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` (or to be the superuser).

Just in case there's any question:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
0
```

Following advice in **pam_cap**(8), I looked for `/etc/security/capabilities.conf`.  On LTS 16 that doesn't exist, but the directory does, so I created the file:

```
CAP_SYS_PTRACE jklowden
```

I also appended this to `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`:

```
# Cf. advice in pam_cap(8)
auth      optional        pam_cap.so
```

Yet a new login cannot attach to the set-gid process.

1. How to display capabilities of a process?
2. Do I have to restart **pam**, or something? How?
3. Is there another file that needs massaging before this will work?
4. Where is a better place to learn about such things?

*Rant*: `sudo -g $gid -p $pid` is no help.  As the fine manual says, *unprivileged  processes  cannot trace processes that they cannot send signals to or  those  running  set-user-ID/set-group-ID  programs,  **for  obvious reasons**.*  It's not actually obvious why I shouldn't be able to trace a process I own from a process in the same group, simply because the file is marked set-group-ID. The policy encourages debugging as the superuser, which is undeniably less secure. [end rant]